# localStorage array reset when added a new item

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I'm currently working on a project where I have to store as many as players as needed into an array of players using localStorage.

I'm in fact able to register those players and modifying their data as I wish, but my problem comes when I try to register a new one, the array with its fields reset to zero. I show an example

I have this array with a player registered:

```
[{"name":"test","score":4,"maxScore":5}]
```

When I add a new player, my array becomes this:

```
[{"name":"test","score":0,"maxScore":0},{"name":"test2","score":0,"maxScore":0}]
```

So as you can see, for every single player I have
, the values of **score** and **maxScore** are reset to 0, and I can't figure it out why, since I haven't worked more than 4 days with localStorage

I'm providing my code next:

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card text-dark bg-dark p-5">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="mb-3">CREATE NEW PLAYER</h2>
        <input
          class="form-control"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Player name"
          name="name"
          #name
          [(ngModel)]="player.name"
        />
        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
          <button
            class="btn btn-primary mt-3"
            type="button"
            routerLink="game"
            [disabled]="player.name === ''"
            (click)="addPlayer(name)"
          >
            JOIN
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public gameService: GameService, public dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  player: Player = {
    name: '',
    score: 0,
    maxScore: 0,
  };

  addPlayer(name: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.gameService.addPlayer({
      name: name.value,
      score: 0,
      maxScore: 0,
    });
    this.dataService.playerName = name.value;
  }
}
```

**game.service.ts**

```
export class GameService {
  players: Player[];

  constructor() {
    this.players = [];
  }

  addPlayer(player: Player) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('players') === null) {
      this.players.push(player);
      localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(this.players));
    } else {
      let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem('players') || '[]'
      );
      let item = localStorageItem.find(
        (item: Player) => item.name === player.name
      );
      if (!item) {
        this.players.push(player);
        localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(this.players));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: I am working with Angular, but in this case it does not affect the development of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work. I changed this:

```
if (!item) {
        this.players.push(player);
        localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(this.players));
      }
```

into this:

```
if (item === undefined) {
        localStorageItem.push(player);
        localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(localStorageItem));
      }
```

And it's working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some updates to your code. In the changes I have made, the application now will add new players without resetting values. It will also rehydrate the list of players on reloading the browser. Hope this helps.

[image]

You can see the changes in action here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-game-with-local-storage?file=src/app/game.service.ts

Comment: I answered my own question with just changing 3 lines of code, but I really appreciate the effort you made there :D

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in the case that you do have an array of players, and you add a new player, the control flow goes as below. I've marked the lines of code that executes in such a case.

```js
addPlayer(player: Player) {
>   if (localStorage.getItem('players') === null) {
      this.players.push(player);
      localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(this.players));
>   } else {
>     let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(
>       localStorage.getItem('players') || '[]'
>     );
>     let item = localStorageItem.find(
>       (item: Player) => item.name === player.name
>     );
>     if (!item) {
>       this.players.push(player);
>       localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(this.players));
      }
    }
  }
```

You get the players from `localStorage` and put that in `localStorageItem` and not `this.players`. However, when `!item`, you `this.players.push(player)` and set it in `localStorage`. You need to append `localStorageItem` in `this.players` as well like below: (Marked the added line with `!`.)

```js
addPlayer(player: Player) {
>   if (localStorage.getItem('players') === null) {
      this.players.push(player);
      localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(this.players));
>   } else {
>     let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(
>       localStorage.getItem('players') || '[]'
>     );
!     this.players.push(...localStorageItem)
>     let item = localStorageItem.find(
>       (item: Player) => item.name === player.name
>     );
>     if (!item) {
>       this.players.push(player);
>       localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(this.players));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It worked, but now, everytime I try to log in with a user that exists, it appends the whole previous list like this: [{"name":"test","score":0,"maxScore":0},{"name":"test","score":3,"maxScore":4},{"name":"test2","score":0,"maxScore":0}]

Comment: then, in that logic, you need to `find` just like you did in `addPlayer` and make sure to account for that.

Comment: Could you please edit the answer you did previosly please @cSharp ? Idk how to do it :'(

Comment: Are you using the same `addPlayer` function for that? If not , please provide relevant code.

Comment: Yes I am, all the code involved is in the question

Comment: You'll have to `console.log` and debug yourself, it's difficult to know what's exactly going on with just this information. One place I can suspect is that even when you find the player, it is going into `!item` block and pushing the player. Check for that.

Comment: Yes, I suspect the same, but this is grinding my gears. Thanks for your time!

Comment: When I register a new player, it returns undefined, but when I log in with an existing player, it returns the player, if it can help @cSharp

Comment: Try changing `localStorageItem.find(...)` to `this.players.find(...)`.